# Ckeditor Plugin - Execute javascript function on specific elements in textarea?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x

I'm creating a plugin for Ckeditor 4.5 and I'm using the classic iframe installation and below is working code which adds a button to the toolbar, that when pressed creates a div.cke-column element and inserts this into the text area wrapping any selected content. What I'm having trouble figuring out is after inserting these divs I would like to call a simple js function on each div with a certain class (the js enables me to have a dynamic properties that change greatly depending on the number of divs in the texarea). Specifically in the code example below, I want to execute a javascript function on each div.cke-column after they are inserted into the textarea of the ckeditor.

```
(function($) {
 CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'simple_columns_plugin', {
  init: function( editor )
  {
   var pluginDirectory = this.path;

  CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load( pluginDirectory + '/lib/customscript.js', function() {

  } );

   editor.addContentsCss( pluginDirectory + '/styles/basic.css' );
   editor.addCommand( 'insert_column_wrapper_command', {
    exec : function( editor ) {
    var columnwrapper = editor.document.createElement( 'div' );
    columnwrapper.setAttribute('class', 'cke-column');
    var innercontent = editor.getSelectedHtml(toString);
    columnwrapper.setHtml(innercontent);
    editor.insertElement(columnwrapper);
    }

   });

   editor.ui.addButton( 'simple_columns_plugin_button', {
    label: 'Insert column', //this is the tooltip text for the button
    command: 'insert_column_wrapper_command',
    icon: this.path + 'images/cw2.gif'
   });
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

I should also add, I am NOT looking to run a javascript function and insert static HTMl, this javascript function that will change when the window is resized so it needs to call a function initially and be available for onresize events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element and even the entire document can be directly access by using the appropiate api functions.  Here is an example that adds a class to an element and an example that directly affects the document using jQuery.  Here are some snippets that showcase the answer

```
var elem = editor.document.findOne('.someclass'); // Get element
elem.addClass('anotherclass'); // add class to element
jQuery( editor.editable().$ ).css( 'color', 'red' ); // directly effect editable content in jQuery.
 var fullcontent = editor.getData(); // Get all content in editable textarea
```